# jQuery mega menu add/remove class on parent menu item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify

I'm trying to build a mega menu in Shopify, this is what I have in my HTML:

```js
$('.has-child').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.child').toggleClass('menu-visible');
  $('.child').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-visible{
color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="parent-main has-child"><a href="/collections">Shop</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class=""><a href="/collections">All Collections</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent-main has-child"><a href="/pages/about">About</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class=""><a href="/pages/">Child link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/pages/">Child link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's working as long as I'm clicking to open and close the same parent menu but the issue I'm having is once I click on one parent menu item and then click on another parent menu item it will open the second menu on the first (so if I click on "Shop" and then click "About" it will open the "About" menu on top of the "Shop" menu). I know I need to get it to remove the "menu-visible" class once I click another parent link but I just don't know how... I tried something with .siblings() but it didn't work, maybe I used it wrong...

Any ideas?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply first remove class from all elements then re-apply on just wanted one.

use `if ($(this).find('.child').hasClass("menu-visible")) {` in order to toggle and remove from others in same time

```js
$('.has-child').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).find('.child').hasClass("menu-visible")) {
    $('.child').removeClass("menu-visible")
    $(this).find('.child').removeClass('menu-visible');
  } else {
    $('.child').removeClass("menu-visible")
    $(this).find('.child').addClass('menu-visible');
  }

  $('.child').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-visible {
  display: block !important;
}

.child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="parent-main has-child"><a href="/collections">Shop</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class=""><a href="/collections">All Collections</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent-main has-child"><a href="/pages/about">About</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li class=""><a href="/pages/">Child link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/pages/">Child link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @gpr2020 Now its working, i fixed it, it had a glich. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.has-child').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(event.currentTarget)
    .find('.child')
    .toggleClass('menu-visible')
    .parent()
    .siblings()
    .find('.child')
    .removeClass('menu-visible')

  $('.child').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: This will not toggle  `this` elements class on and off

Comment: @ikiK Have you looked at the example? It will toggle classes where relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but with this method I can't open and close the main nav item

Comment: I don't have to, they do not close on double click.

Comment: Im sorry to say but `currentTarget is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need is to add the display none to all the other children and toggle the one that you are clicking, by using the **not()** function you can achieve this without an if statement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .d-none{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>






<ul class="parent">
  <li class="parent-main has-child"><a href="/collections">Shop</a>
    <ul class="child d-none">
      <li class=""><a href="/collections">All Collections</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent-main has-child"><a href="/pages/about">About</a>
    <ul class="child d-none">
      <li class=""><a href="/pages/">Child link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/pages/">Child link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.parent-main a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.child').not($(this).parent().find('.child')).addClass('d-none');
            $(this).parent().find('.child').toggleClass('d-none');

        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is what I already have, so after I click "Shop" and then click "About", I want it to close the "Shop" option

Comment: I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
This one should solve your problem.


$('.has-child').on('click tap', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('.child').hasClass('menu-visible')) {
        $(this).find('.child').removeClass('menu-visible'); // toggle current
    } else { 
        $('.menu-visible').removeClass('menu-visible'); // close all
        $(this).find('.child').addClass('menu-visible'); // open current
    }
});
```